# Is it possible to run .out files in windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, file-extension

I have a file with the extension .out . I'm running windows 10. From what I understand, .out files are generated while coding in C and C++ in Linux. I was wondering if there was any way in which I could execute the file in windows. Renaming it's extension to .exe gave me an error saying the file was incompatible with 64-bit version of windows.

So is there any way I could execute the file, or better yet, view it's contents as proper code so I can work with it, while using Windows?

Comment: You could install a virtual machine manager (e.g., VirtualBox), and install  a copy of Linux in it, then run that executable in that copy of Linux. Pretty sure Windows won't run Linux executables directly though.

Comment: what if he needs that executable to run in windows environment? I wonder if disassembling the executable to assembly code under linux and then taking the .asm file and assembling in windows would work. I hope a compiler junkie chimes in on this

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII Converting the binary format is possible to some degree, but then the next problem is the completely different set of runtime libs. (Even a hello-world program with only standard language features calls many OS-dependent function before and after main when in compiled form). Just recompiling (if the code is sufficiently platform-independent) is waayy easier.

Comment: A file extension doesn't necessarily tell you anything about the file's content. Unix compilers use the name `a.out` for generated executables by default, but you should almost always specify a more meaningful name. Are you asking about an `a.out` file? How was it generated?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Running in a linux VM won't guarantee to get it running actually, unless it was compiled on the exact same platform.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Right--it's a necessary (but not sufficient) condition.

Comment: It's very unlikely that this file is actually a Linux executable. And if you had to do research to find out that it's an executable, the next step is definitely *not* trying to run it! If it really is an `a.out` file, you can't view it as "proper code", because it's an executable, not source.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII, even if you dissassemble it the assembly wont run.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII Additional information to my previous comment, some hours ago: In theory, each problematic function call could be replaced manually by function calls (or larger code pieces) which do the same thing for the other OS. But a) this won't work automatically, because b) this is basically porting the program to another OS. While working in the binary format. ... Porting is easier with the source (and even easier if the source is written independly of the OS: only recompiling then). Nobody will try to port a binary file if the source could be used instead, it's just too hard

Comment: I got the file as part of an online challenge. I already have the information that the file was generated using C code. I just need to run it.
I tried installing Virtualbox, but ran into a host of problems. I'm hating how a tiny .out file is making me go into larger and larger issues lol.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of directly converting a linux executable to Windows format.
You'll have to recompile or use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), It allows running Linux commands in Windows environment.

Comment: You should note, that using Cygwin still needs recompilation as well. Also POSIX standard is unrelated in this case.

Comment: Cygwin doesn't allow Linux executables to be run. They are windows executables with cygwin code which mimicks linux calls to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

[a.out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) is not neccessarily related to C or C++, it can be generated from any other kind of compiler/assembler. If you read the article, then you can see that it isn't even guaruanteed that this actually is what you may think of `a.out` format.

In order to execute it, the only possible way to achieve this is to install a Unix OS to execute it, but this again wont guaruantee that it really can be executed, because there may be dependencies or the wrong OS, etc..

To view the content of the file, there are different utillities on different platforms. For example you can use `objdump` on `Linux` or `Cygwin/Windows` to take a look at it. You can use a disassembler and see if you can make sense of it. On Windows you can use `IDA` which covers a broad range of fileformats and may be able to dissect it.

Now that you managed to take a look inside it, there is the next issue you asked for, by converting it. This is a tedious process though, because you must do it by hand. If IDA could identify it, you get a good start because you now have an assembly source as a starting point, but it will likely not assemble, and certainly not run on your target platform (Windows).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm trying hard to get the code out of the file. Online dissassembler and boomerang decompiler (Which gave a partial C code) has helped, but it looks like I can't do anything without having access to a Linux system.

Comment: I was wondering, is there any website that allows me to upload and run .out files online, like the way it would run from a Linux terminal?

Comment: Not sure, but I would doubt it,